# How to access individual elements of Matrix4 in OGRE

Tags: matrix, element, ogre

How can I access individual elements of Ogre::Matrix4? I saw the API of OGRE 1.9, but I couldn't find a way to access each matrix element individually. I want to access them using row, column numbers.

`Ogre::Matrix4::operator[](size_t iRow)` looked closest to what I need, but I couldn't make out what it meant to do or how to use it.

Also posted on [OGRE::help forum](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=90746).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access it as if it was an array (which internally [it is](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_matrix4.html#a949708616d61b1c520d04bd9b0577324)).

```
Ogre::Matrix4 mat;
mat[0][0] = mat[3][3] = 1.5f;
Ogre::Real r1 = mat[0][0]; // First element
Ogre::Real r2 = mat[3][3]; // Last element
```